# MFC-J825DW printer doesn't accept the correct router password that works for computers

Tags: printer, network-printer

I try to enable WLAN (wireless), it finds my router network, but the password that works for all my other devices doesn't work for the printer. I tried several times, and I know the password is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the type of wireless encryption you are using is support by the device. Some older devices do not support newer encryption standards like WPA2-AES. Try WPA2-TKIP or WEP(less secure). If those both don't work your only option is ethernet cord or open wifi.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the printer, and it accepted the password. I don't know why.

Before, the printer restarted after switching to wireless, but apparently that was not enough of a restart. xp

tip: afterwards, I ran into an issue of the print job not being sent to the printer. For this, i just downloaded and reinstalled the full software from the website, restarted my computer, and it worked.